# figures in multiple rows

Tags: subfloats

I want to have a figure with subfigures like this:

[image]

I tried to use \usepackage{subfig} but I get an error:
! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfig package.

Comment: Try with the `subfigure` environment, defined in `subcaption`.

Comment: In my opinion, the proposed "numbering" (with lowercase roman letters) of the subfigures is very hard to follow. The tall subfigure you're currently labelling as "c" should really be numbered "e", i.e., be numbered *last*.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following? The code uses the `subcaption` package, which may (or may not) be compatible with the document class you use. Which document class *do* you use?

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure})}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{first}
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{second}
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip % some vertical space between subfigures a/b and c/d...
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{third}
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fourth}
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2\linewidth]{fifth}
\caption{} 
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!